# Tangent spheres Tan,tan,tan for spheres(balls)

Tags: autocad, cad

How to draw mutually tangent spheres of radii 1,2,3,4,etc incrementally.
I have easily drawn mutually tangent spheres of radii i.e, r1,r2,r3 on a pythagorean triangle of 3,4,5 sides in autocad but HOW TO DRAW a 4th sphere of r4 mutually tangent to r1,r2,r3 spheres?
What is the coordinates of the center of that 4th sphere?
So for I has never found a function or software for that. If there is any for sphere packing please mention.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the spheres S1, S2, S3 and S4.
You already got S1, S2 and S3 drawn, willing to draw S4 now.

Go to the plane formed by the centers of S1, S2 and S3 (containing that triangle you mentioned).

Draw tan-tan-radii circle in that plane with radii equal to S4's, tangent to S1 and S2 (not S3). Mark the center of this circle and call it Base-1-2. (If you want, draw a line in that point perpendicular to the plane, to find the point easier in the next steps).

In this same plane, draw a line connecting centers of S1 and S2, call it Axis-1-2.

From Base-1-2, draw a line that ends perpendicular to Axis-1-2. This endpoint will be the origin of the plane you will go next.

Go to the plane that is perpendicular to Axis-1-2 and contains Base-1-2.
(Do that with UCS command, using ZAxis option, select the origin point mentioned, and some point over Axis-1-2)

In that plane, draw a circle centered in Axis-1-2 and passing through Base-1-2.

That circle represents all possible positions of S4's center related to S1 and S2.

Now, do the same thing again, now using S1 and S3 instead of S1 and S2. (New Axis-1-3, new Base-1-3 and everything).
The resulting circle will be all possible positions of S4's center related to S1 and S3.
(You can do the same thing a third time using S2 and S3, but it's not necessary)

The intersection points (there are two) of the resulting circles will be the two possible centers of S4.

---

If you're interested in programming, here's a link I think is good (I didn't test it)

http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/02/sphere-packing-in-autocad-creating-an-apollonian-packing-using-f-part-1.html

Comment: i have already tried that before. Didn't worked.
It will be graceful if send me a dwg like that. Because it is bothering me.

Comment: With 1, 2, 3, 4 radii?? Or with instructions?